# Op-amp gain circuitry

Tags: operational-amplifier

For background, I have an LV-25P voltage sensor that is used to measure AC voltages. The output of this sensor is an induced current that causes a voltage drop across a resistor I have connected to ground. The maximum output that will be obtained across that resistor is from -4.55V to +4.55V. This part works just fine.

I recently constructed an op-amp board that will scale this input voltage in the range of 0V to 3.3V for a microcontroller to be able to read it. The circuit I came up with was a two-stage op-amp circuit that consists of an inverting op-amp with a gain, and then an inverting and summing stage. The first stage is responsible for reducing the peak-to-peak voltage of the signal to 3.3V (should still be centered at 0V) and the second stage is responsible for offsetting the waveform by 1.65V so that the output is from 0-3.3V.

Schematic for reference:
[image: Op-amp circuit schematic]

The second stage of this circuit seems to work perfectly, but I'm having some strange results with the first stage. The signal is correctly inverted, and the peak-to-peak voltage of the waveform is 3.3V as intended, but there is a strange DC offset that is shifting the signal down to be centered around -0.5V rather than at 0V.

The input signal from a function generator is the yellow waveform, and the output signal from the op-amp board is in blue. Both signals are DC coupled on the oscilloscope to include their DC components.

[image: First stage waveform]

I can compensate for this offset by altering the potentiometer on the second stage, but I'd like to know what would be causing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really just have a capacitor in series with the + input? You haven't provided a path for the bias currrent. You can connect the + input to ground, or add a resistor from the + input to ground.

The bias current from the + input is charging the cap in series with the input, causing your amplifier's output to shift accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This fixed my issue. I had generally followed a few designs I found online as I am relatively new to this and they seem to have led me astray.

Answer (score 2):

Without going through the rest of the circuit -- you have no DC path to ground from the noninverting terminal of your first stage op amp.  That could be your whole problem right there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This was the issue.